# minishift error under windows 8, vm cannot be accessed?

Tags: openshift, minishift

Here is my configurations

Windows 8
virtualbox 5.2.14
minishift-1.20.0-windows-amd64

Here are the messages I got when I tried to start minishift:

> minishift start --vm-driver virtualbox
>   -- Starting profile 'minishift'
>   -- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
>   -- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
>   -- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.9.0' is valid ... OK
>   -- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.9.0' is supported ... OK
>   -- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
>   -- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
>   -- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
>   -- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
>   -- Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
>   -- Starting Minishift VM ...................................................... FAIL E0708 00:03:28.368248    7292 start.go:414] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded. Retrying.
>   Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded

It seems the VM is running but for some reasons not accessible. Any ways to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issues some days ago and managed to solve it by installing the latest version of Win32-OpenSSH.

Please take a look at https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/1565 and https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH for a detailed description of the issue and an installation guide.